# Input a set of points to a clojure function

Tags: data-structures, input, clojure

I am writing an algorithm in Clojure which takes in a set of points which represents an polygon. Another input is a point, and the output needs to be whether the point lies inside the polygon or not.

My question is how do I input the set of points to the function? What data structure in clojure would be most appropriate - A set, vector, list etc. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you should start with the simplest possible solution, so in this case I'd probably do it with a list of points, with each point expressed as a 2-dimensional vector, e.g.

```
(def my-polygon (list [0 0] [1 0] [1 1] [0 1]))
```

This should be fine for your application.

However depending on how you ultimately want to use / maniplulate these polygons in the future there are some alternatives to consider:

- If you want interoperability with Java code (e.g. drawing the polygon in a frame using Swing/Java2D), you might want to use instances of an appropriate Java class (e.g. one of the subclasses of **[java.awt.geom.Point2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html)**) as the individual points. This will give you less idiomatic Clojure code, but will give you better Java interop
- You might want to use a **vector instead of a list** - particularly if you are going to be using large polygons and applying different algorithms that need **indexed access** to the individual points

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. But how do I modify it to return the first element of the input list of vectors? (I new to clojure syntax)

Comment: Well you can do "(first my-polygon)" to get [0 0] for example - is that what you mean? And "(rest my-polygon)" will get you the list of the remaining points, assuming that you want to write some form of function that iterates or recurses over these.

Comment: Basically my question is - why does the following code give an error - (def in-poly [arg]
  (first arg))

Answer (score 7):

Presumably the order of points matters, so that the shape ABCD is not the same as the shape ABDC?

In which case you need some sort of data structure which preserves order. This means that a list or vector is acceptable, but a set is not.

But you could also write your function to take anything seqable -- so that if you later want to change from vector to list or vice versa, you don't have to change your function. Program to an interface, not to an implementation.